# How to add a "," to a url automatically

Tags: url

I'm trying to pass our caller ID on to our customer records. When a call is placed a web browser navigates to our customer database and it enters the caller ID automatically. However, our customer database doesn't like the format. I need to place a comma after the first name.

The URL takes the tag {$caller_id_name}, populates it with the caller ID from the caller and launches into our system.

Calls currently come in reading "Smith John"

They need to come in reading "Smith, John"

I can't just insert a comma into the URL string because $caller_id_name is one object. First and last name are handled as one.

Comment: It would be helpful, perhaps, if you could include the language you're using.

Comment: If this is smarty, than `{$caller_id_name|replace:' ':', '}` (but than you should add smarty tag to the question)

Comment: Oops, yes! This is smarty.

Comment: skobaljic - this is returning "{$caller_id_name|replace:%27%20%27:%27,%20%27}" Any ideas?

Comment: Returning from where? You should be able to save your smarty template without encoding. What CMS are you using, x-cart? Go edit your templates via FTP.

Comment: It's returning that in the web browser address bar when I'm launched to our customer DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the comma to your variable.  {str_replace(' ', ',', $caller_id_name)}

Edit: mis read your question.

Comment: Hmm, this results in:

"{str_replace(%27%20%27,%20%27,%27,%20$caller_id_name)}"

Answer (score 0):

Well the Asterisk dial plan in place won't allow us to work with smarty variables. Thanks for the help with this everyone!